# Error returns list indices must be integers or slices not tuples at line 121

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, tuples, genetic-algorithm

I have this current population where I specific how many in the population

```
[[10000]
 [00010]
 [01000]]

[[10000]
 [10000]
 [00001]]
   .
   .
   .
[[01000]
 [00100
```

And am trying to select and crossover...genetic algorithm steps

This is the code for the population above

```
for i in range(nbrofindv):
   init_pop = numpy.zeros(pop_size, dtype=int)
   init_pop = init_pop.astype(int)
   k = 0
   l = 0
   for k in range(taskn):
      l = random.randrange(solperpop - 1)
      init_pop[k][l] = 1
      arr.append(l)
   matlist.append(init_pop)
```

And this the fitness function

```
def cal_fitness(task1 , task2 , task3 , matix , mmax,array):
   fitness = numpy.empty(len(matix))
   S1=numpy.empty(len(matix),dtype=int)
   z=0
   for i in range(len(matix)):
       S1[i] = task1[array[0+z]]+task2[array[1+z]]+task3[array[2+z]]
       z+=3
       if S1[i] <= mmax:
           fitness[i] = S1[i]
       else :
           fitness[i] = 0
   return fitness.astype(int)
```

When I try the selection

```
 def selection(fitness, num_parents, population):
    fitness = list(fitness)
    parents = numpy.empty((num_parents, len(population)))
    for i in range(num_parents):
        max_fitness_idx = numpy.where(fitness == numpy.max(fitness))
        parents[i,:] = population[max_fitness_idx[0][0], :]
        fitness[max_fitness_idx[0][0]] = -999999
    return parents.astype(int)
print(selection(cal_fitness(t1,t2,t3,matlist,300,arr),2,matlist))
```

It returns **list indices must be integers or slices not tuples**

This is the full code

```
import numpy
import random
import pandas
wsn = numpy.arange(1, 6)
taskn = 3

t1 = numpy.random.randint(30, 200, size=len(wsn))
t2 = numpy.random.randint(30, 200, size=len(wsn))
t3 = numpy.random.randint(30, 200, size=len(wsn))

print('\nGenerated Data:\t\n\nNumber   \t Task 1  \t   Task 2  \t   Task 3\n')
ni = min(len(t1), len(t2), len(t3))
for i in range(ni):
    print('\t {0}    \t   {1}    \t    {2}  \t\t {3}\n'.format(wsn[i], t1[i], t2[i], t3[i]))
print('\n\n')
qmin = 50
qmax = 140

for i in range(len(t1)):
    if t1[i] <= qmin or t1[i] >= qmax:
        # t1=numpy.delete(t1,i)
        t1[i] = 0
for i in range(len(t2)):
    if t2[i] <= qmin or t2[i] >= qmax:
        # t2=numpy.delete(t2,i)
        t2[i] = 0
for i in range(len(t3)):
    if t3[i] <= qmin or t3[i] >= qmax:
        # t3=numpy.delete(t3,i)
        t3[i] = 0
i = 0
m = max(len(t1), len(t2), len(t3))
if t1[i] == 0 and t2[i] == 0 and t3[i] == 0:
    t1 = numpy.delete(t1, i)
    t2 = numpy.delete(t2, i)
    t3 = numpy.delete(t3, i)
    i += 1
solperpop = len(wsn)
gen = 20
j = 0
pop_size = (taskn, solperpop)
print('population size: {}'.format(pop_size))
# for j in range(ni):
#   pop_size=list(solperpop,taskn)
matlist = list()
print('\n\n')
i = 0
k = 0
nbrofindv=5
arr=[]
for i in range(nbrofindv):
    init_pop = numpy.zeros(pop_size, dtype=int)
    init_pop = init_pop.astype(int)
    k = 0
    l = 0
    for k in range(taskn):
        l = random.randrange(solperpop - 1)
        # arr[i][k]=l
        init_pop[k][l] = 1
        arr.append(l)
    matlist.append(init_pop)


print(arr)
count1 = 0
for m in range(len(matlist)):
    print('\n')
    count1 += 1
    print(matlist[m])

print('\n\n\n')
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
pandas.set_option('display.width',None)
zipped=pandas.DataFrame(list(zip(*matlist)),columns=['Individual 1','Individual 2','Individual 3','Individual 4','Individual 5'])
print(zipped)
print('\n\n')
# print('the initial pop has ', count1, ' individuals')
i=0
for i in range(len(wsn)):
    if t1[i] == 0:
        if init_pop[0][i] != 0:
            init_pop[0][i] == 0
    if t2[i] == 0:
        if init_pop[1][i] != 0:
            init_pop[1][i] == 0
    if t3[i] == 0:
        if init_pop[2][i] != 0:
            init_pop[2][i] == 0



def cal_fitness(task1 , task2 , task3 , matix , mmax,array):
   fitness = numpy.empty(len(matix))
   S1=numpy.empty(len(matix),dtype=int)
   z=0
   for i in range(len(matix)):
       S1[i] = task1[array[0+z]]+task2[array[1+z]]+task3[array[2+z]]
       z+=3
       if S1[i] <= mmax:
           fitness[i] = S1[i]
       else :
           fitness[i] = 0
   return fitness.astype(int)
# print(len(matlist),len(cal_fitness(t1,t2,t3,matlist,250)))
#print('\t\n  individual  \t fitness \n')
fitness=cal_fitness(t1,t2,t3,matlist,300,arr)
ni=len(matlist)
w=0
for i in range(ni):
    print('individual:',wsn[i],' | fitness:',fitness[i])
    print('\t\n {0}   \t \t  \t \n'.format(matlist[i]))

print('\n\n')


def selection(fitness, num_parents, population):
    fitness = list(fitness)
    parents = numpy.empty((num_parents, len(population)))
    for i in range(num_parents):
        max_fitness_idx = numpy.where(fitness == numpy.max(fitness))
        parents[i,:] = population[max_fitness_idx[0][0], :]
        fitness[max_fitness_idx[0][0]] = -999999
    return parents.astype(int)

print(selection(cal_fitness(t1,t2,t3,matlist,300,arr),2,matlist))

def crossover(parents, num_offsprings):
   offsprings = numpy.empty((num_offsprings, parents.shape[1]))
   crossover_point = int(parents.shape[1]/2)
   crossover_rate = 0.5
   i=0
   while (parents.shape[0] < num_offsprings):
       parent1_index = i%parents.shape[0]
       parent2_index = (i+1)%parents.shape[0]
       x = random.random()
       if x > crossover_rate:
           continue
       parent1_index = i%parents.shape[0]
       parent2_index = (i+1)%parents.shape[0]
       offsprings[i,0:crossover_point] = parents[parent1_index,0:crossover_point]
       offsprings[i,crossover_point:] = parents[parent2_index,crossover_point:]
       i+=1
    return offsprings
```

Comment: Which lines is this?

Comment: there is an error with the brackets here: `[[10000][00010][01000] [[10000][10000][00001]]...[[01000][00100][00010]]` , this shows on my basic linter in vscode.

Comment: @toyotaSupra the line for the error? Is when I print the function and the 2nd line of for loop in the selection function

Comment: I will provide the full code cause for me it shows no errors @D.L

Comment: You need comma in tuple.

Comment: Am not sure I understand can you give me an example, and would that solve the problem? @toyotaSupra

Comment: ([10000][00010][01000], [[10000][10000][00001]]...[[01000][00100][00010]). Post snippet code not whole code.

Comment: The full code was for another comment as he had errors I didn't have so I added the full code, So adding commas will solve the problem Is what you are saying? @toyotaSupra

Comment: In line 142 should be i += 1 instead of  i=+1

Comment: Thank you but the error I currently have is in the selection function in the second line of the for loop

Comment: In line 120 should be fitness =

Comment: No it's correct and the error is in 121 not 120

Comment: Sorry. Let me rephrase it. It should be like this... where(fitness = numpy. You shouldn't used ++ in numpy.where. It should be Boolean.

Comment: No I understood you, it's actually correct am trying to find where the best fitness is at which index to return the best population this is the concept of the selection of genetic algorithm if you are not familiar with it

Comment: The code you posted has clear indentation errors. Please [edit] to post the actual code you want to ask about, ideally as a [mre]. On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to correctly format your code with indentations preserved.

Comment: I didn't notice that, I will fix it now @tripleee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`population` in your example is a List of arrays, so you can not index it as arrays. Using `[max_fitness_idx[0][0], :]` is array-like indexing; So, this line will be stuck:

```
parents[i, :] = population[max_fitness_idx[0][0], :]

# population:
# [array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]), array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])]
```

If we need such indexing so one way is to convert `population` list to a numpy array by `np.array(population)`, which will have shape `(5, 3, 5)`, so `np.array(population)[max_fitness_idx[0][0], :]` will have shape `(3, 5)`:

```
np.array(population)[max_fitness_idx[0][0], :]
# [[0 0 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 0 0]
#  [1 0 0 0 0]]          <-- below examples will refer to it
```

Since, `parents`'s shape is `(2, 5)` and `parents[i, :]`'s shape is `(5, )`, You can not assign `3 * 5 = 15` values of aforementioned code to just `5` positions in a row of `parents`. I don't know what the code will do, but if you want such indexing, you must specify another row number for the 2nd dimension e.g.:

```
[max_fitness_idx[0][0], 2, :]
# [1 0 0 0 0]

parents[i, :]
# [4.065923e-215 8.124414e-206 1.1446152e-200 2.287846e-191 9.8291696e-182]

parents[i, :] = np.array(population)[max_fitness_idx[0][0], 2, :]
parents[i, :]
# [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Or you can do this without converting list to NumPy array, but with list indexing step by step, e.g.:

```
population[max_fitness_idx[0][0]]
# [[0 0 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 0 0]
#  [1 0 0 0 0]]          <==

population[max_fitness_idx[0][0]][2]
# [1 0 0 0 0]] 

parents[i, :] = population[max_fitness_idx[0][0]][2]
parents[i, :]
# [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

The running code will be:

```
wsn = numpy.arange(1, 6)
taskn = 3

t1 = numpy.random.randint(30, 200, size=len(wsn))
t2 = numpy.random.randint(30, 200, size=len(wsn))
t3 = numpy.random.randint(30, 200, size=len(wsn))

# print('\nGenerated Data:\t\n\nNumber   \t Task 1  \t   Task 2  \t   Task 3\n')
ni = min(len(t1), len(t2), len(t3))
# for i in range(ni):
#     print('\t {0}    \t   {1}    \t    {2}  \t\t {3}\n'.format(wsn[i], t1[i], t2[i], t3[i]))
# print('\n\n')
qmin = 50
qmax = 140

for i in range(len(t1)):
    if t1[i] <= qmin or t1[i] >= qmax:
        # t1=numpy.delete(t1,i)
        t1[i] = 0
for i in range(len(t2)):
    if t2[i] <= qmin or t2[i] >= qmax:
        # t2=numpy.delete(t2,i)
        t2[i] = 0
for i in range(len(t3)):
    if t3[i] <= qmin or t3[i] >= qmax:
        # t3=numpy.delete(t3,i)
        t3[i] = 0
i = 0
m = max(len(t1), len(t2), len(t3))
if t1[i] == 0 and t2[i] == 0 and t3[i] == 0:
    t1 = numpy.delete(t1, i)
    t2 = numpy.delete(t2, i)
    t3 = numpy.delete(t3, i)
    i += 1
solperpop = len(wsn)
gen = 20
j = 0
pop_size = (taskn, solperpop)
# print('population size: {}'.format(pop_size))
# for j in range(ni):
#   pop_size=list(solperpop,taskn)
matlist = list()
# print('\n\n')
i = 0
k = 0
nbrofindv = 5
arr = []
for i in range(nbrofindv):
    init_pop = numpy.zeros(pop_size, dtype=int)
    init_pop = init_pop.astype(int)
    k = 0
    l = 0
    for k in range(taskn):
        l = random.randrange(solperpop - 1)
        # arr[i][k]=l
        init_pop[k][l] = 1
        arr.append(l)
    matlist.append(init_pop)

# print(arr)
count1 = 0
for m in range(len(matlist)):
    # print('\n')
    count1 += 1
    # print(matlist[m])

# print('\n\n\n')
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pandas.set_option('display.width', None)
zipped = pandas.DataFrame(list(zip(*matlist)), columns=['Individual 1', 'Individual 2', 'Individual 3', 'Individual 4', 'Individual 5'])
# print(zipped)
# print('\n\n')
# print('the initial pop has ', count1, ' individuals')
i = 0
for i in range(len(wsn)):
    if t1[i] == 0:
        if init_pop[0][i] != 0:
            init_pop[0][i] == 0
    if t2[i] == 0:
        if init_pop[1][i] != 0:
            init_pop[1][i] == 0
    if t3[i] == 0:
        if init_pop[2][i] != 0:
            init_pop[2][i] == 0


def cal_fitness(task1, task2, task3, matix, mmax, array):
    fitness = numpy.empty(len(matix))
    S1 = numpy.empty(len(matix), dtype=int)
    z = 0
    for i in range(len(matix)):
        S1[i] = task1[array[0 + z]] + task2[array[1 + z]] + task3[array[2 + z]]
        z += 3
        if S1[i] <= mmax:
            fitness[i] = S1[i]
        else:
            fitness[i] = 0
    return fitness.astype(int)


# print(len(matlist),len(cal_fitness(t1,t2,t3,matlist,250)))
# print('\t\n  individual  \t fitness \n')
fitness = cal_fitness(t1, t2, t3, matlist, 300, arr)
ni = len(matlist)
w = 0

# for i in range(ni):
#     print('individual:',wsn[i],' | fitness:',fitness[i])
#     print('\t\n {0}   \t \t  \t \n'.format(matlist[i]))
#
# print('\n\n')


def selection(fitness, num_parents, population):
    fitness = list(fitness)
    parents = numpy.empty((num_parents, len(population)))
    for i in range(num_parents):
        max_fitness_idx = numpy.where(fitness == numpy.max(fitness))
        parents[i, :] = population[max_fitness_idx[0][0]][2]      # <== modified
        fitness[max_fitness_idx[0][0]] = -999999
    return parents.astype(int)


parents = selection(cal_fitness(t1, t2, t3, matlist, 300, arr), 2, matlist)  # <== modified


def crossover(parents, num_offsprings):
    offsprings = numpy.empty((num_offsprings, parents.shape[1]))
    crossover_point = int(parents.shape[1] / 2)
    crossover_rate = 0.5
    i = 0
    while parents.shape[0] < num_offsprings:
        parent1_index = i % parents.shape[0]
        parent2_index = (i + 1) % parents.shape[0]
        x = random.random()
        if x > crossover_rate:
            continue
        parent1_index = i % parents.shape[0]
        parent2_index = (i + 1) % parents.shape[0]
        offsprings[i, 0:crossover_point] = parents[parent1_index, 0:crossover_point]
        offsprings[i, crossover_point:] = parents[parent2_index, crossover_point:]
        i += 1                       # <== modified
    return offsprings                # <== modified

print(crossover(parents, 2))         # <== modified
```

**I tried to show the cause of the error (as it is the title and aim of this question) and how to correct it, assuming the written code is satisfying the OP need; Not proposing a new code based on that OP need.**

Comment: Am trying to select a certain number of parents from the population I have, I specified 2 for example. And It needs to return to me the two fittest of the population elements. Am not sure if you run the solution you gave me but It either gives the same error for the np.array or cannot broadcast input array from shape 3,5 to 5,

Comment: @Atraxia I have run the code without running `crossover(parents, num_offsprings)` and that work after modifying the code as in my answer. For testing `crossover`, what will be the inputs?? what are `parents` and `num_offsprings`?

Comment: I fixed both the problems, Thank you. It worked thank you but am actually trying to pick the whole matrix as a parent which means it should print two matrices but it only prints two arrays like [[01000][00010]] would you be able to suggest something for this?